# Отображение размера шрифта через VS Code

Tags: html, css

При вёрстке макета требуется задать размер шрифта `font-size: 8px;`
Пишу его в редакторе **Visual Studio Code**, а он, в браузере ниже `font-size: 12px;` не уменьшается, только может увеличиваться.
Использую браузер **Google Chrome**.
Подключал файл `normalize.css`, `reset.css` - результат нулевой.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём здесь моя ошибка?

P.s.
Код предоставить из CSS? Именно фрагмент какой части?

```
.text {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 360px) {
    font-size: 10px;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Можете поделиться кодом? Надо глянуть

Comment: И так не говорят — форумчане) Во-первых, это не форум, а сообщество. Во-вторых, если уж так надо — говорите "члены сообщества".

Comment: VS Code тут не при чём вообще

Comment: Здравствуйте. Код предоставить из CSS? Именно фрагмент какой части?